# SQL Database "create Tabe"

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i made some changes at my Database and since then the app crashes everytime when i launch it. My Code is:

```
public static final String TABLE_TRANSACTION = "transaction";
public static final String COLUMN_TRANSACTION_ID = "TRANSACTION_ID";
public static final String COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DATE_CREATED = "TRANSACTION_DATE_CREATED";
public static final String COLUMN_TRANSACTION_ISOVERVIEW = "TRANSACTION_ISOVERVIEW";
public static final String COLUMN_TRANSACTION_NAME = "TRANSACTION_NAME";
public static final String COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION = "TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION";
public static final String COLUMN_TRANSACTION_TYPE = "TRANSACTION_TYPE";
public static final String COLUMN_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT = "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT";
public static final String COLUMN_TRANSACTION_REPEAT_CYCLE = "TRANSACTION_REPEAT_CYCLE";
public static final String COLUMN_TRANSACTION_REPEAT_DAY = "TRANSACTION_REPEAT_DAY";
public static final String COLUMN_TRANSACTION_REPEAT_ACTIVE = "TRANSACTION_REPEAT_ACTIVE";

 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TRANSACTION = "create table "
        + TABLE_TRANSACTION + " ( "
        + COLUMN_TRANSACTION_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DATE_CREATED + " VARCHAR(16), "
        + COLUMN_TRANSACTION_ISOVERVIEW + " VARCHAR(10), "
        + COLUMN_TRANSACTION_NAME + " VARCHAR(4096), "
        + COLUMN_TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION + " VARCHAR(4096), "
        + COLUMN_TRANSACTION_TYPE + " INTEGER, "
        + COLUMN_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT + " FLOAT, "
        + COLUMN_TRANSACTION_REPEAT_CYCLE + " VARCHAR(20), "
        + COLUMN_TRANSACTION_REPEAT_DAY + " VARCHAR(20), "
        + COLUMN_TRANSACTION_REPEAT_ACTIVE + " VARCHAR(10) );";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TRANSACTION);
}
```

And i get this Error:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "transaction": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table transaction ( TRANSACTION_ID integer primary key autoincrement, TRANSACTION_DATE_CREATED VARCHAR(16), TRANSACTION_ISOVERVIEW VARCHAR(10), TRANSACTION_NAME VARCHAR(4096), TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(4096), TRANSACTION_TYPE INTEGER, TRANSACTION_AMOUNT FLOAT, TRANSACTION_REPEAT_CYCLE VARCHAR(20), TRANSACTION_REPEAT_DAY VARCHAR(20), TRANSACTION_REPEAT_ACTIVE VARCHAR(10) );
```

Can you say where the mistake is? Thx for Help

Comment: `TRANSACTION` is a reserved keyword, in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TRANSACTION` is a [reserved keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), "which may not be used as the names of tables, indices, columns, databases, user-defined functions, collations, virtual table modules, or any other named object". You will need to name your table something else.

Comment: Ok Thanks, on the first tries it worked. I have changed it and now it works.